# Xcode - Could not launch - No such file or directory

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I found this really annoying problem with Xcode and unable to fix it!
I've tried ways such as:

1. Disconnecting my device, deleting the app from my device (but actually the app isn't even built), quitting Xcode and deleting the Derived Data folder
2. Feleting `Required device capabilities` in `info.plist`

My device is iPhone 4, iOS version 5.0.1.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 I've tried it, but it doesn't work

Comment: create new project...it its working then match both project plist...

Answer (score 0):

You must be facing this problem when trying to run app on device directly from XCODE. 
You create a new profile and delete previous profiles created with same certificate. Now install new profile clean build you project and try to run. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can try is to delete the app in you iPhone and then restart the device. I have seen this before.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I failed to run it in my IPhone. So basically, my app itsn't installed yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem like crazy recently whenever I get a new version of XCode or iOS. It appears to still update the app on your phone but not connect for debugging purposes.

Today, I had to do a full hardware restart of my iPhone for a different reason. That is, I held the Lock and Home buttons until the device shut off and then restarted it.

Bingo, next time I tried Xcode it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your iOS version looks catchy to me! Have you checked your project deployment target version compatibility with the current version of iOS on your device?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solutions here to no avail.  I was only able to resolve this by: 
uninstalling the app, 
hard-rebooting the ios device, 
shutting down xcode, 
reverting recent changes to the generated file [myproj].xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/[myproj].xccheckout (thanks to source control), 
deleting the contents of /Users/[myUser]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData, 
opening the project again, 
cleaning the project.

I have no idea which one(s) of these steps solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this problem, but none of the cleaning and restarting helped for me. Then I tried xcode13beta, and it gave a better error message, that for my case was about mismatching bundle id for the compiled product and what was "requested to launch".

For my case I think it is a xcode bug, as I have different info.plist files in different configurations set up with different bundle id (for some uninteresting signing reasons) correctly, but it was still trying to launch with the wrong bundle id. For me I fixed it by setting the bundle id in both of the info.plist files to `${PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}`, and suddenly it started to work.

So in summary,

1. Try newer Xcode, it might give you a better error message
2. It might be some shenanigans with bundle ids, if you have some weirder setup there, might be worthwhile to revisit how it is setup.

Answer (score 0):

This just occured to me when I deleted the app right before it finished installing (because I wanted a fresh install of my app). In cases like this, reinstalling the app solves the issue.